# Chats seem to be offline

Tags: support, chat

Just tried going to the chats for the Meta SO and Workplace SO and I cant get to either of them.

Is there a issue for everyone?

Comment: Oh no! Looks like you'll have to actually get some work done.

Comment: There still is Meta @CodyGray.

Comment: @CodyGray Why...why would you say that on a Friday of all days :(

Comment: @Cody: I *will* get my work not-done, and a missing chat is not gonna hinder me!

Comment: Oh goodness, is it Friday already? But I still have a bunch of close votes left to use!

Comment: Can anyone **not** in Europe confirm if chat is down for them too?

Comment: @Oded In fact, chat seems to be back up here in Switzerland.

Comment: Yes, for me too. Thanks @Bart

Comment: @Oded Working for me now.

Comment: We're looking into the cause of this now